# Does GLES20 do MRT

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Android `GLES20 SDK` provides only `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and no `glDrawBuffer` or `glDrawBuffers` functions. Does this mean rendering to texture is out?

Am I right in thinking that the `Tegra development` NV extension only apply to `NDK`?

Answer (score 0):

Recently support for GL_TEXTURE0, GL_TEXTURE1 has been provided. When I asked, it was not supported.